Finding a basis for the kernel and image of T
Given the linear transformation
$$ T : \text{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \text{Mat}_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$$ defined by:
$$T(X) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} X + X \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Find a basis for $ker(T)$ and $Im(t)$.
In a given solution, they opted to take basis $B = (e1,e2,e3,e4)$ and using row reduction on $[T]_B$ , got that $$ker(T) = span(\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac 14 & -1 \\ -\dfrac 12 & 1 \end{pmatrix})$$
The reasoning behind was that those are the solutions to the linear system of $[T]_B$ .
but $$T(\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac 14 & -1 \\ -\dfrac 12 & 1 \end{pmatrix}) \neq \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
Am i missing somthing?

Let's try to find a matrix $X$ such that $T(X)=0$

It's the zero matrix. but what's wrong in the strategy given in the solution? because it also makes sense

Correct, $ker(T)=0$. The strategy is good so check the calculations.
